# Chat font is too small on mobile

Tags: bug, chat, design, mobile-web

On my samsung note 4 the font looks small on the entire https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com. I know this is a taste thing (I personally like bigger fonts) but it is inconsistent with the rest of stack overflow. I was browsing a lot of posts right before I found the chat section and it was jarring enough to make me uncomfortable and immediately exit out.

Note in the screenshot the difference between the text of the loading message and the rest of the site. Maybe it is not picking up on my browser's settings (110% text scaling on chrome dev Android)?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow that's a big difference. I just checked and it gets computed to 15px on site and 11px on chat, which is pretty tiny.